# What will default(interface) return?

Tags: c#

I found some code, but I'm not sure what is the purpose of return `default` of *interface*?

The `interface` is implemented by few `class`es

```
 public ISocketDevicePart Parent => default(ISocketDevicePart);

 public interface ISocketDevicePart
 {
     ISocketDevicePart Parent { get; }
     IEnumerable<ISocketDevicePart> Childs { get; }
     IXYOffset Offset { get; set; }
 }
```

I'm not sure about result. Should it return `null` **always**?

Comment: just google a little. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/default-value-expressions) what I find for just 0.43 seconds of searching

Comment: @vasily.sib In defense: there is no reference to `interface` in the docs. It might confuse beginners.

Comment: @PatrickHofman that's true, but after reading this docs the next question that beginner should search for is _"is interface is value type or reference type?"_. Just another 0.56 second of google searching.

Comment: What to do with the remaining .01 second I wonder then. ;) @vasily.sib

Comment: @PatrickHofman Ask a question here anyway? Surely .01 seconds are enough

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto just in case:)

Comment: Yea, it was just to be sure. In other hand, isn't better to use `return null;` ?

Comment: @EmerG There is no difference, accept for clarity. Do as you please.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the default of an interface-typed variable is `null` (it is treated as a reference type).

For completeness, you can view the entire `default()` list in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/default-value-expressions).